# STM32L052 Analog-to-digital converter on registers

Tags: c, stm32, processor, bare-metal

I went through the entire configuration of the Analog-to-digital converter [ADC]. When I worked on the registers, I made a mistake somewhere. Below are the configurations. The debugger via ST-Link after connecting 3.3 [V] to pins used in the project, during the measurement assigns them a value of 0x00 which indicates a failure. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(void)
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |=  RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN; 
    //ADC attach

    RCC->IOPENR = RCC_IOPENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_IOPENR_GPIOBEN;      

    GPIOB->MODER = GPIO_MODER_MODE14_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODE15_1;
    //ADC_IN8 & ADC_IN9

    /* configure ADC */
    ADC1->ISR &= ~ADC_ISR_EOCAL & ~ADC_ISR_AWD;  
    //calibration flag, WATCHDOG flag

    ADC1->ISR |= ADC_ISR_ADRDY;
    ADC1->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADSTART;  
    //The software is allowed to write smp bit only when ADSTART=0

    ADC1->SMPR |= ADC_SMPR_SMP_0 | ADC_SMPR_SMP_1 | ADC_SMPR_SMP_2;  
    //111: 160.5 ADC clock cycles

    ADC1->CFGR1 &= ~ADC_CFGR1_SCANDIR;  
    //Scan Direction 0: Upward scan (from CHSEL0 to CHSEL18)

    ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC_CFGR1_AWDCH_3 | ADC_CFGR1_AWDEN | ADC_CFGR1_WAIT | ADC_CFGR1_CONT | ADC_CFGR1_AUTOFF; 
    //AWDCH[4:0]: Analog watchdog channel selection, Continuous Mode

    ADC->CCR |= ADC_CCR_LFMEN | ADC_CCR_VREFEN; 
    //Low Frequency Mode,  V REFINT enable

    ADC1->CHSELR |= ADC_CHSELR_CHSEL8 | ADC_CHSELR_CHSEL9 | ADC_CHSELR_CHSEL17; 
    //Channel Select 8 & 9  

    ADC1->IER |= ADC_IER_EOCIE | ADC_IER_EOSEQIE | ADC_IER_OVRIE | ADC_IER_EOSMPIE; 

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_COMP_IRQn); 
    NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_COMP_IRQn,3);

while(1)
    {
        ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;// | ADC_CR_ADSTART; 
        //Start the ADC conversion

        while ((ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRDY)); 
        //Wait for stand up

        while ((ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)); 
        //wait for conversion flag

        ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL; 
        //End of the calibration

        delay(100); 

        uint16_t napiecie = ADC1->DR;
        uint8_t hi = ((napiecie >> 8) & 0xff);
        uint8_t lo = ((napiecie >> 0) & 0xff);

        //DISABLE ADC
        if ((ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADSTART) != 0){
            ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTP;
            while ((ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADSTP) != 0);
        }
        ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADDIS; //ADC disable command
        while ((ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADEN) != 0);
        ADC1->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADSTART & ~ADC_CR_ADEN;
        //ADC1->CR &= ~ADC_ISR_ADRDY; //Clear the ADRDY bit in ADC_ISR register by programming this bit to 1 (optional).
    }

void ADC1_COMP_IRQHandler(void)
/* Interupt ADC */
{
    if(ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC){
        uint16_t napiecie = ADC1->DR;
        uint8_t hi = ((napiecie >> 8) & 0xff);
        uint8_t lo = ((napiecie >> 0) & 0xff);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if adc does not two clock domains

Comment: Which register is 0x00? Why does the debugger assigns that value? Sry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL; //End of the calibration : according to the docs I read, this STARTS a calibration, in your while(1), but not even in a valid way as you just set ADC_CR_ADEN: "You must make sure that the ADC is not yet enabled, and if it is disable it. You can then set the ADCAL bit which will start the calibration. Then wait for the calibration to finish before clearing it by writing a 1 to EOCAL in the ISR register."

Comment: Most of the other codes available do use ADC_CR_ADSTART to start the conversion... (or ADC1->CR |= (1UL << 2);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two times you used lines like

```
ADC1->ISR &= ~ADC_ISR_EOCAL | ~ADC_ISR_AWD;
```

which looks really strange to me, as if the defines are 1 bit wide, which they most likely are, their bitwise OR is 0xFFFFFFFF (all F, no 0) and you're not changing the ISR and the CR (later in the code) at all! You need to use a bitwise AND, no?

```
ADC1->ISR &= ~ADC_ISR_EOCAL & ~ADC_ISR_AWD; 
...
ADC1->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADSTART & ~ADC_CR_ADEN;
```

Else some working code is available at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287073/get-internal-temperature-or-voltage-stm32l0/287162
https://github.com/ChristopherJD/STM32L053R8/blob/master/Intern_Project/ADC.c
and https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=47644832

Comment: thanks you for pointing it out, you are completely right about this. Made me feel ashamed rn x) ~changed the first post. I was changing from |= to ~, still does not solve the problem after all.